# How to add combo box in WMD

Tags: javascript

How to add combo box in **WMD(Markdown)**

Answer (score 0):

Markdown doesn't have any special syntax for making a dropdown like it does lists. Instead, you would need to insert actual HTML directly into your Markdown code. That may or may not work, depending on what html tags (if any) are allowed during entry.